# How can I protect my addon code from scammers?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am working on an addon which I am close to finish and I'll share it **totally** free with a game community. But... As in outer life, this game community has some "weird" guys. These "weird" guys takes your work, whatever it is, they change some things so to make it looks a bit different, they put a price on it, they move your hard work into an other server, where you are unknown as person and they earn a lot of money of it!!! So what I need is your advice and your knowledge so to encrypt my addon code or protect it in some way from all this situation.

Comment: depending on the license you used this is actually allowed, and completely legal. Also do you really want to share code that nobody can read through? you know that your code is safe, but what ensures that to others.

Comment: Unless you distribute a modified build of blender, and even then you would have to provide the source code with it, I'm afraid you can't prevent people from looking inside your add-on's contents if you want to distribute it

Answer (score 1):

Especially if it's targeted to a specific community, your best shot (IMO) would be to advertise what you are doing as widely as possible. Post about your addon in forums, on your homepage/blog (if you have...), maybe also Blender Market etc. **as early and transparently as possible**.

Then, whenever you encounter one of the scammers trying to make money of your code, put out a comment linking to your original post and tell everybody that they can get the same value for free.
Spreading knowledge about your work helps others to spot such fraudulent offers early.

Having traceable proof of your original code ownership might come handy if some of the scammers turn real nasty and try legal action.

Other that that, I dont't think that you have a real chance by obfuscating your code. All you do is make life difficult for yourself and the legitimate users.

P.S: You might find this an interesting read in the context: https://www.blender.org/press/re-branding-blender/